# how to concatenate string with special character in SAS

Tags: string, sas

I'm trying to concatenate the two following strings:

```
String1 = /data/projects/flat_file/meteo/
String2 = *.json
```

In sas i make this code:

```
%let string1 = /data/projects/flat_file/meteo/;
%let string2 = %sysfunc(compress('*.json',"'"));
```

But when i try to concatenate them in this way:

```
%let merge = %sysfunc(cats(&string1., &string2.));
```

It doesn't work. When i try to put i don't see nothing.
Have you any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are going into a comment with that `*.json`, use %str to avoid this (that compress is useless)
The contatenation between the 2 strings generate a `/*` that is also the symbol to start a comment.

```
%let string1 = /data/projects/flat_file/meteo/; 
%let string2 = %str(*.json); 
%put &string1.;
%put &string2.;
%let merge = &string1.&string2; 
%put &merge;
```

let me know if you will need any further clarification.

If anything is shown in your log anymore, is because your system is still locked in that comment, run the following code to "unlock" your sas system:

```
*'; *"; *); */; %mend; run;
```

Comment: Don't think that can be it. A * cannot start a comment in the middle of a statement. And macro quoting cannot prevent a * from being seen as the start of a comment when it is the start of a SAS statement.  If you try your code without the %str it should still work. Away from SAS for several hours so I can't test.

Comment: sorry quentin, it doesn't work without %str.
When you go through the concatenation of string1 and string2 you will have the last char of string1=/ and the first char of string2=*. Hence you will have '/*', that could start a comment anywhere in your code.
Please, be sure of your answer before posting.

Comment: Ahh.  So it's not a * comment but a /* comment. That makes more sense.  Suggest adding that as part of your explanation.

Comment: @stat you rock. I try your code ant it works well. Thank you so much

Comment: @Quentin good idea, thank you.
Pierpaolo you're welcome (di nulla).

Comment: @stat the %str(*.json) put special char that i can't manage . Any idea??

Comment: Pierpaolo, please be more specific, I can't find this special char in both macro variable and in dataset variable.
%let string1 = %str(/data/projects/flat_file/meteo/); 
%let string2 = %str(*.json); 

%put &string1&string2;

data prova;
try="&string1&string2";
output;
run;

please post your code and where you find this special char.

Comment: @stat i post my problem in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812097/how-to-pass-a-string-to-a-macro-sas-without-special-char

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are generating the /* sequence that indicates the beginning of a block comment.  So you need to quote some part of that.  One simple change is to use %qsysfunc() instead of %sysfunc() so that the resulting string is quoted.

```
%let string1 = /data/projects/flat_file/meteo/; 
%let string2 = *.json ;
%let merge = %Qsysfunc(cats(&string1,&string2)) ;
```

However using the CATS() function to concatenate strings in macro code will not work well for many macro values because of the way that the CATS() function tries to determine the data type of its arguments.  Instead you can just use normal macro syntax to concatenate and add some macro quoting.  I find that for this type of path assignments it is easiest to quote the dividing /.  So leave the trailing slash off of your paths and add it back when concatenating.

```
%let path = /data/projects/flat_file/meteo ; 
%let file = *.json ;
%let sep = %quote(/) ;
%let fullpath = &path.&sep.&file;
```